# Importance of order in registering provider and configuring a module in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

it seems that from angular's point of view the order of registering of a service provider and the module configuration code is important: in order for the configuration code to find the provider, the provider should be registered before.

This was a total surprise for me, as I thought that angular first processes all provider registrations, to make them available for DI, and then calls config callbacks, like this:

module.config(function(myServiceProvider) {...});

Please see here a very short test that demonstrates the problem. It fails on "unknown provider", you can see it in the JS console: http://plnkr.co/edit/jGJmE2Fq7wOrwubdlTTX

Am I missing anything here? Is it an expected angular behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this behavior has changed in more recent versions of Angular (not sure when exactly). I modified your Plunker to point from 1.0.7 to 1.3.0 and it worked without error as you had originally expected.

Similar example of code that works:
    var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);

```
myModule.config((myServiceProvider) => {
});

myModule.service('myService', () => {
});
```

Running a config for a provider before the provider is registered with the module should work just fine as you were expecting.

**Reference**

For reference, this reported issue appears to be the one to have fixed it: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6723

Answer (score 0):

The Angular documentation for [module](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) state that:

> **Recommended Setup**
>   While the example above is simple, it will not scale to large applications. Instead we recommend that you break your
>   application to multiple modules like this:
>
> - A service module, for service declaration
> - A directive module, for directive declaration
> - A filter module, for filter declaration
> - And an application level module which depends on the above modules, and which has initialization code.

As you are using a single module that you call `app`, you are creating a dependency between that module's `config` and declaration of a `provider`.  What you should have done is to place all your providers into a separate module, such as:

```
var appr = angular.module('appr', [])
  .provider('myService', function() {
    this.$get = function() {};
  })
```

Then you declare the dependency of your `app` using:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['appr']);
```

Check out the updated Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ym3Nlsm1nX4wPaiuVQ3Y?p=preview

Also, instead of using the generic `provider`, consider using more specific implementation of `provider` such as `controller`, `factory` or `service`.  Take a look at [Module API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.Module) documentation for more detail.

Comment: As you can see in this (http://plnkr.co/edit/iueOj8RuvGGSwI80MePb?p=preview) plunker, you can also avoid to have the modules in global scope. Once you define them, you can reference with the one-arg version `angular.module('myModule')` and avoid globals.

Comment: I know that separating the provider to a different modules solves the problem. But the solution you suggest is hardly long-lasting - separating all providers to a separate module does solve a specific problem, but when the configuration is made in this very module, it requires yet another separation, leading to endless modules to solve the problem. I would expect angular to either prioritize provider() higher than config(), so it's called afterwards, or at least document this as being equal (using the same queue, as can be seen from their implementation).

Comment: @Stas I am not sure I understand your comment.  As `config` is used to configure a module, it is fair that Angular expect you to have declared all dependencies of that module, including all providers, before `config` is ran.  I do not see why this would lead "to endless modules to solve the problem".  A simple example could be that you create a "UtilitiesServices" module with all providers you need, add that one module as a dependency to your App module, then run the `config` on your App.  What am I missing?